# Visualize the effect of adding another constraint

Tags: geometry, inequality

I have 2 eqns
$$ x_1+4x_3\leq4$$

$$ x_2+4x_3\leq4 $$
$$x_1\geq0$$
$$x_2\geq x_3\geq0$$ 
By drawing geometrical figure I have vertices whose co-ordinates is $(0,0,0) , (4,0,0) (0,0,1) ,(0,4,0) ,(4,4,0)$
I want to include an in-equality named $$x_1+x_2+x_4+x_5\geq \epsilon$$
 I cant visualize the result of adding this .
Is (0,0,1) point is out of the geometrical figure for adding the constraint ? Can you please help me to visualize the affect of adding another constraint ?

Comment: What space are your constraints on? You seem to have 5 independent coordinates, which might explain why you're having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: If you draw an geometrical figure , you might get a polytope which is still in 3D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, try and visualize the solutions to $x_1+4x_3-4=0$. Compare with $mx-y=0, x^2+y^2-1=0.$ Then consider the regions that are separated from eachother by this curve. If only two regions meet, one must be greater than 0 and the other less than it. Now, you can consider this region in 3D if you use 3 coordinates in your original formulation, but to combine it with constraints not in exactly those 3 variables, you must extend that figure along the span of those other variables. For example, $x^2+y^2 \leq 1$ and $-1\leq z \leq 1$ would combine to describe a cylinder from $-1$ to $1$.

With this setup in place, one simply takes the intersection of all the regions described by the individual constraints to obtain the region described by the simultaneous inequalities.

All the constraints can be viewed as having coefficient-0 terms for the variables that don't appear, which is another way of seeing that the figure satisfying the inequality will have unconstrained axes for each variable beyond those appearing in that inequality.